# I can't play GTA V because my PC keeps dropping fps

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I have an Acer Aspire 3 A315-54 notebook.

Intel i5-10210U 1.6ghz.

8GB RAM 2670MHz.

1tb hdd.

Intel UHD graphics iGPU.

I see videos of people with laptops with worse hardware than mine and running GTA V with better performance than mine, as soon as I open the game and play for a few minutes it doesn't crash but after about 10 minutes of gameplay it starts to experience drops insane fps every second making it impossible to play
I needed a solution to this problem because it doesn't make sense for computers and notebooks with worse hardware than mine to perform better just in GTA V, I've already lowered the graphics to the point where the game looks like GTA SA but it still has fps drops

Comment: Time to buy an SSD

Comment: `after about 10 minutes of gameplay it starts to experience drops ` It is probably trying to load a new area of the map.

Comment: @Gantendo or the laptop has poor cooling and takes 10 minutes to saturate the heatsink and go into thermal throttling. Also 8GB RAM doesn't seem that much for a large game like GTA V, even though they claim the minimum spec is 4GB i've seen many people complain with limited or slow swap space.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your laptop has insufficient heat sinks.

Now depending on how long you have owned it, it might be worth it to open it up and clean all the dust out.

Depending on the environment you live in, it could be caked with dust.